# comparing three lists of texts to see matching words

Tags: python

Hello I have written a function to read and compare words between three lists of sentences which works if **any** of the words are match it returns text else `False`, basically taking in a list of web-elements from `selenium` and checking
if text matches any of list of  `keywords`, what i want to do is modify it that if 1 or 3 or more it returns link after checking i.e if only two words match returns `False`.(this function will return link if any of words matches and one of key word matches link)
I want to this function will return link if (1,3,4,5...)of words matches and one of key word matches link (only 0,2 returns False) 
`links` and `texts` are equal length.

```
from selenium import webdriver
d = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r"C:\Users\test\PycharmProjects\chromedriver")
sentence = "hello world from python"
url_keywords = [".com",".edu"]
d.get("https://google.com/search?q={}".format(sentence))
y=d.find_elements_by_xpath("//a[@href]")
a=check(y,url_keywords)
li=[]
if a:
    check(y)
else:
    pass

def check(y,url_keywords):
    links = [i.get('href') for i in y]
    texts = [i.text_content() for i in y]
    for i, link in enumerate(links):
        for keyword in url_keywords:
            if keyword in link:
                for word in sentence.lower().split():
                    if word in texts[i].lower():
                        return link

    return False
```

if there is any easier way of doing so, please advice

Comment: @hansolo the code will be quite long for retrieving the web-elements and url_keywords

Comment: What is that "sentence" variable? Where did you define it?

Comment: " modify it that if 1 or 3 or more it returns link after checking " - > Please try explain this more clearly. 1 or 3 or more what? Matches? Lists that have matches?

Comment: @Neil Apparently the OP wants only odd number of matches.

Comment: @Neil so basically each time key word is found in link and word is found in text of link that is one match

Comment: @virmis_007 not odd only 0,2 returns false every other number return link

Comment: @Neil i did add a small code, but Always url_keyword will vary

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
from selenium import webdriver

# Use descriptive names for variables, not single letters.
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r"C:\Users\test\PycharmProjects\chromedriver")

# Use UPPERCASE for constants
SENTENCE = "hello world from python"
URL_KEYWORDS = [".com",".edu"]

driver.get("https://google.com/search?q={}".format(sentence))
elements  = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//a[@href]")
result = check(elements, url_keywords)


def check(elements, url_keywords):
    links = [i.get('href') for i in elements]
    texts = [i.text_content() for i in elements]

    # Use zip to avoid so much nesting! Also means you can drop the index variable "i"
    search_space = zip(links, texts)

    for link, text in search_space:
        #Let's keep track
        number_of_matches = 0  
        for keyword in url_keywords:
            # Create a separate function, again to avoid so much nesting! (see "Zen of Python")
            match = is_match(keyword, link, text)
            #If match is true int(match) will be 1, otherwise 0
            number_of_matches += int(match)
        if has_correct_number_of_matches(number_of_matches):
            return link
        else:
            return False

def normalise(string):
    """
    There is often quite a bit that we want to do to normalise strings. And you might want to extend this later. For this reason, I again make a new function, and also add in the "strip" method for good measure and as an example of extending the normalisation behaviour.
    """
    return string.lower().strip()

def is_match(keyword, link, text):
    if keyword in link:
        for word in normalise(sentence).split():
            if word in normalise(text):
                return True
        else:
            return False
     else:
        return False

def has_correct_number_of_matches(number_of_matches):
    """Now that this function is isolated, you can define it however you want!
    """
    return number_of_matches not in (0, 2)
```

Comment: i will accept answer, but you should know since you mention "Zen of python" PEP 8 suggests all variable names **&** constants should start with lower case

Comment: No, it doesn't. "
Constants

Constants are usually defined on a module level and written in all capital letters with underscores separating words. Examples include MAX_OVERFLOW and TOTAL." Right there https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#constants

Comment: I am not against you or anything man, you know i had 1 minute to write the above script (above check) that is why it is in poor formatting

Answer (score 0):

Without having your source data, the easiest way to handle this is as follows:

```
[i for i in sent1.lower().split() for j in sent2.lower().split() for k in sent3.lower().split()
    if i == j == k]
```